# Import ActionBar Sherlock to Android Studio

Tags: actionbarsherlock

I'm try to import the latest version of ActionBar Sherlock into my project using the latest version of Android Studio. I've put the ActionBarSherlock project in my projects directory. I've selected File->Import Settings. When I point it to the ActionBarSherlock, it says Can not find file ...\AndroidstudioProjects\ActionBarSherlock\settings.jar.

What the heck is the settings.jar file? This was not in the distribution. How do I create it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of File->Import you can simply just add ABS to project using gradle in your *build.gradle* file insert this line into **dependencies** section:

```
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
```